# What is the value of $\log_b m^{\log_b n}$?

Tags: logarithms

What is the value of the following expression?

> $$\log_b \left( m^{\log_b n} \right)$$

As far as I know it should be:

$$\log_bn\;\times\;\log_bm$$

Can it be simplified further? If so how?

Also, I read somewhere that it is equal to:

$$\log_b m$$

If that is correct, how is it possible?

Also, if it matters, the place where I read about the second answer, used base $10$.

Here's the image of the book where I found it:

[image]

Comment: Is it (log (m ^ log n)) or (log m) ^ (log n) ?

Comment: It's the the former - log (m ^ log n)

Comment: Yeah, I can't figure out what's going on in the second rectangle either... but I do get that $\log u=0$ from the first rectangle. If you do as well, then don't worry about it.

Comment: @Lovsovs How do you get $log\;u = 0$ from the first rectangle? I'm not that experienced with logarithms.. Please help me and thanks for your time.

Comment: I've added the explaination now. You need to know the log-rule $\log \left( \frac{u}{v} \right)=\log u - \log v$. I hope that helps. I'm just going to shamelessly put this out there, but if you'd like, you can "accept" my answer (the tick under the vote up/down-arrows) and make me very happy! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean $\log_b\left( m^{\log_bn} \right).$

Then $\log_bn\;\times\;\log_bm$ is correct, and that cannot be simplified any further. Perhaps you are thinking about $\log_b(n \times m)=\log_bn+\log_bm$?

And it cannot equal $\log_bm$ - where would the $n$ have gone?

---

**EDIT** to explain recently introduced picture in question:

$\log u=\log\frac{z}{y} \log x+\log\frac{x}{z} \log y+\log\frac{y}{x} \log z=(\log z-\log y)\log x+(\log x-\log z)\log y+(\log y-\log x)\log z=\log z \log x-\log y\log x+\log x\log y-\log z\log y+\log y\log z-\log x\log z=0$

Comment: If  n= b, then it would be true.

Comment: @Lovsovs Please see the edited question :)

Comment: is it an identity that $log(x).log(y)\,=\,xy$? And as far as accepting your answer goes, I definitely will but first, I need to understand, isn't it. Btw, I have upvoted it.

Comment: No it very much isn't! I introduced some short-hand notation (to save some time), but since it confuses you, I'll change it... just a sec.

Comment: @Lovsovs Oh yes... now I have understood it (before you made the edit)... took me a while... btw, your edit is simpler to understand (at least for me). Thanks a lot.

Comment: @FarhanAnam Glad I could help, and thank you for the accept! :)

Answer (score 2):

Wow, I don't like that book at all.
It is true that
$$
\log u  = \log x^{\log (z/y)} + \log y^{\log(x/z)} + \log z^{\log(y/x)} 
$$
implies
$$
\log u = \log \frac zy + \log \frac xz + \log \frac yx,
$$
*because the right-hand formulas in both equations are equal to zero,*
but since what we need to do is to to *show* that the right-hand side
of the first equation is zero, we can't legitimately use that fact to
argue this implication.

It certainly is not true that in general
$\log x^a + \log y^b + \log z^b = a + b + c,$
so I really can't see how that step of the solution was justified.

I think a better approach is never to write the expression
$x^{\log (z/y)} y^{\log(x/z)}  z^{\log(y/x)}$ at all.
Instead, go back one step in the chain of equations $(1)$ in the book's
"solution", where we see the equal expression
$x^{\log z - \log y} y^{\log x - \log z}  z^{\log y - \log x}$.
That's an easier expression to work with.
Set
\begin{align}
u &= x^{\log z - \log y} y^{\log x - \log z} z^{\log y - \log x}, \\
\log u &= \log \left(x^{\log z - \log y} y^{\log x - \log z}
                  z^{\log y - \log x}\right) \\
  &= \log \left(x^{\log z - \log y}\right)
       + \log\left(y^{\log x - \log z}\right)
       + \log\left(z^{\log y - \log x}\right) \\
 &= (\log z - \log y)\log x + (\log x - \log z)\log y
                  + (\log y - \log x)\log z \\
 &= \log z \log x - \log y \log x + \log x \log y - \log z \log y
                  + \log y \log z - \log x \log z \\
 &= 0.
\end{align}

Comment: The book is good otherwise but this one came as a surprise.

Comment: OK, even in a good book sometimes something bad sneaks past the author and the editors. If it only happens once or twice, that's what errata and corrected editions are for.